# Unable to GET from JSON API

Tags: json, swift

I have tried following a variety of tutorials, and I am unable to progress on getting data from this API. I did manage to succeed on a simpler JSON ], but this one is eating up my time.
First, the JSON:

```
{
    "object": {
        "array": [
            {
                "id": 48,
                "name": "Job No.# 48",
                "description": "blah",
                "start_at": "2021-03-05T13:15:00.000+11:00",
                "end_at": "2021-03-05T14:15:00.000+11:00",
                "map_address": "blah road"
            },
            {
                "id": 56,
                "name": "Job No.# 56",
                "description": "Do it",
                "start_at": "2021-06-22T11:30:00.000+10:00",
                "end_at": "2021-06-22T13:30:00.000+10:00",
                "map_address": " blah"
            }
        ],
        "person": {
            "id": 52,
            "first_name": "Bob",
            "last_name": "Newby",
            "mobile": "0401111111",
            "email": "bob@mail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And now my attempt at decoding it:

```
struct api_data: Codable {
    let object : Object
}

struct Object: Codable {
    let array : [array]
    let person : Person
}

struct array: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : Int?
    let start_at, end_at : Date?
    let duration : Float?
    let cancellation_type : String?
    let name, description, address, city, postcode, state : String?
}

struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : Int?
    let first_name, last_name, mobile, email : String?
}

class FetchShifts: ObservableObject {
  @Published var shifts = [Shifts]()
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "realURLhiddenForPrivacy")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("myToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let array_data = data {
                    let array_data = try JSONDecoder().decode([array].self, from: array_data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.array = array_data
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And how I attempt to present it:

```
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchArray()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(array.shifts) { shft in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(shft.name!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated, not sure where it is I go wrong here, been at it for 5-7 hours going through tutorials.

Comment: Your **start_at** and **end_at** are string in response and you are trying to decode it as a Date that seems to be the prominent reason.

Comment: Mistake 1: struct Worker: Codable, Identifiable -> struct worker: Codable, Identifiable

Comment: Mistake 2: struct Shifts: Codable, Identifiable -> struct shifts: Codable, Identifiable

Comment: You did one thing that most dont, you did a do/catch and printed the `error`, and not only the `error.localizedDescription`, until there, it was almost perfect. Since you are new, and seeing "Not entirely sure if this error relates", instead of just `print(error)` do ` print("Error on JSONDEcoder: \(error)")`. ie, give a context to your error in logs. That way you'll be able to identify in console exactly what's part of the caught `error` and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend using app.quicktype.io to generate models from JSON if you're unfamiliar with it. Here's what it yields:

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: String
    let payload: Payload
}

// MARK: - Payload
struct Payload: Codable {
    let shifts: [Shift]
    let worker: Worker
}

// MARK: - Shift
struct Shift: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, shiftDescription, startAt, endAt: String
    let mapAddress: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case shiftDescription = "description"
        case startAt = "start_at"
        case endAt = "end_at"
        case mapAddress = "map_address"
    }
}

// MARK: - Worker
struct Worker: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName, lastName, mobile, email: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case mobile, email
    }
}
```

Then, to decode, you'd do:

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: shift_data)
    let shifts = decoded.payload.shifts
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note that in Swift, it's common practice to use camel case for naming, not snake case, so you'll see that `CodingKeys` does some conversion for that (there are automated ways of doing this as well).

---

Update, based on comments:

Your code would be:

```
if let shiftData = data {
  do {
      let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: shiftData)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.shifts = decoded.payload.shifts
      }
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for referring app.quicktype.io, absolute gem of a tool for anyone wanting to dive into Codable implementation.

Comment: Where I have `let shifts` is where you should assign to `self.shifts` inside your `async` block.

Comment: No difference in the last view except that you don't need the `!` after `name` since in the models I've provided, `name` isn't an optional property.

Comment: @Jason I've updated so that you can see *exactly* what it should look like

Comment: @Jason could be because I didn't explicitly mark `Shift` as `Identifiable`. See my edit (`struct Shift : Codable, Identifiable`) and try that. Or, explicitly pass an `id` in your list: `List(fetch.shifts, id: \.id) { shft in ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining custom keys, you can automatically use
`keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` for your JSON decoder, and could specify custom date format or even throw a custom error in your decoder implementation.

```
struct Worker: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let mobile: String?
    let email: String?
}
struct Shift: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String?
    let description: String?
    let startAt: Date?
    let endAt: Date?
    let mapAddress: String?
}
struct Payload: Codable {
    let shifts: [Shift]?
    let worker: Worker?
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let payload: Payload?
}

class MyCustomDecoder: JSONDecoder {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        self.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
    }
}

// Usage
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    let response = try MyCustomDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response)
}
```